# CDG baggage claim before or after immigration?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, luggage, cdg

I have a transfer in CDG (both in T1), but they are on separate tickets. I'm not entering the Schengen area, nor coming from it.

Can I check baggage for my flight to CDG and collect it before immigration or do I have to go through immigration if I want to have a checked bag?

Comment: What are the two airlines (and ideally, the two flights)? Some airlines may be able to check-through luggage to another airline even on separate tickets if they are in the same alliance, have code-share agreements, or some other types of agreements.

Comment: They are not part of the same alliance nor have any code share agreements that I know of, but I'll call and ask to see if they can do that anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Baggage claim* on an international flight is *always* after immigration.

You can talk to your airline if they can transfer over the baggage to the other airline (in some cases this is possible) but if that doesn’t work out and if you must take your baggage and check it yourself then it is always going to be after immigration.

<strike>And in that case you’re definitely entering Schengen area and will require a visa if your passport doesn’t have Schengen  visa exemptions.</strike>

<sub>Since you appear to be a savvy traveler who knows what he is asking, it is safe to assume that you know your immigration requirements. Hence there is no need for the standard TSE project visa & boarding fear.</sub>

Comment: Which of course means OP would have to enter the Schengen Area, and would need to have a visa to do so if their nationality does not allow for visa-free entry.

Comment: The last clause should read "if your passport doesn’t have a Schengen visa exemption."  The Schengen airport transit visa is not applicable if the traveler has to enter the Schengen area.  Also note the important point raised by the other answer.

Comment: Even if baggage is transferred, if they need a visa the airline might not allow the passenger to board on 2 separate tickets if they don't have a Schengen visa

Comment: I never claimed they don’t need a visa for the first flight. OPs question was about baggage and I’ve clearly answered that they will have to pass through immigration.

Answer (score 18):

Baggage claim will be after the border control (Immigration).

Please note that if your nationality doesn't have visa-free access to the Schengen area and you don't have a valid visa, **the airline might not even allow you to board or check-in for the first flight**. please contact your airline to clarify tour situation in that case and ask if they can check the bags for you, they might do it if they have a partnership with the other airline.

Comment: This point cannot be stressed enough.

Comment: No problems on entering the Schengen area, but that's a great call-out for those who need a visa and not have one.